# Formatting the headings

Tags: fonts, sectioning, numbering

SX

I'm still fairly new to latex and hoping to get some help on how to do the formatting of the font for chapters and headings. I've been looking around the forum for hours now, trying to see if I could piece it together myself but had to give up in the end.

I basically have two problems.

**1. Desired format**

1 Chapter
1.1 Section
1.1.1 Subsection
1.1.1.1 Subsubsection

I found this possible with:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0em}{\bf\LARGE\thechapter.~}
```

However this also puts a 0. in my Abstract chapter, which I don't know how to remove. It also creates double numbering in the ToC.

Is there a way around this so I can keep the numbering except for Abstract and not have double numbering in ToC?

**2. Change Font**

I found out how to change the font for the entire document. I simply used:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[ebgaramond]{mathdesign}
```

I only wish to use Garamond as the normal text while using another font (http://surl.dk/e1e/ from this list most likely) for headings. How do I go about changing the fonts of the headings?

I'm on Mac OSX 10.9.4 using TeXworks.

[image: screenshot of example]

I appreciate any help.

Full code:

```
%% Preamble start

%%%% --- Basic ---

\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}


%%%% --- Typography ---

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{titlepic}

%%%% --- Headings ---

%
% ?????
%

%%%% --- Math and Chem specifics ---

\usepackage[ebgaramond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}  %Easier to write chem compounds ie. \ce{H2O} and \ce{PO4^2-}

%% Preamble end

\title{Report Ex}
\author{John Smith}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter{Abstract}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\\
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Background}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\\
%
\subsection{Details}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\\
%
%
\section{History}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\\
%
\section{Analysis}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{document}
```

Comment: We need to see a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to be of much help, I'm afraid. Right now, we don't know what class you are using or how you are coding your abstract or much of anything. However, note that `mathdesign` has no `ebgaramond` option. So you are getting default `mathdesign` fonts (if any). Your `.log` or console output will include warnings about this. Also, don't use `\bf`. It is deprecated. Use `\bfseries` instead. And I think, though I'm not sure, you're putting `\thechapter` in the wrong argument of `\titleformat` (hence the toc issue).

Comment: I didn't know about the restrictions of the ebgaramond font. It was just the only way I could get garamond to work (sorry, still very much new to latex). How should I implemt my use of fonts?
I have added photo to the original post.

Comment: I just posted my full code as is.

If I try using \usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign} it just gives an error:
! LaTeX Error: Command `\circledS' already defined.

Comment: The closest code I could find to work is this but it gives numbering to Abstract & Contents as well, which I do not want.
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0em}{\bf\LARGE\thechapter.~}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, this should do what you want. I've commented the code a bit.

To use the `garamond` option, you need to install URW Garamond. You can do this using [getnonfreefonts-sys](https://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) which is a script you can use to easily install additional fonts. Make sure you use the `sys` version when you run the script.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}  %Easier to write chem compounds ie. \ce{H2O} and \ce{PO4^2-}
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[british]{babel}% if you want UK - otherwise use american
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{parskip}% don't set \parindent and \parskip manually (and you'll want positive parskip if parindent is zero so this should work OK)
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\bfseries\LARGE}{\thechapter~}{0em}{}

\title{Report Ex}
\author{John Smith}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter*{Abstract}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Background}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

\subsection{Details}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

\section{History}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

\section{Analysis}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{document}
```

EBGaramond lacks bold by design. So if you want to use bold, you need to use another garamond. If you want to stick to EBGaramond, don't use `mathdesign` as it does not support EBGaramond and is causing you to end up with a mixture of EBGaramond for regular weight and something else for bold which cannot be good.

Comment: If I try to run that I get:

[1] (./TexEx.toc) [2]
Chapter 1.
[3] (./TexEx.aux) ){/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/ly1/texn
ansi.enc}
!pdfTeX error: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file ugmm8a.pfb): cannot open Type 1 font 
file for reading
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Comment: something about:
Package mathdesign/mdugm Warning: Package 'amsfonts' shouldn't be used in conjo
nction with package mdugm, on input line 16.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I forgot that URW Garamond is not in TeX Live either. I think if you want garamond and you want bold, you are going to need to use the `getnonfreefonts-sys` script to install additional fonts.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to install that on OSX? I did stumble upon "getnonfreefonts-sys" before, but could not find any descriptions for Mac users

Comment: @user2927919 I've updated my answer and added a link. Those instructions work fine on a Mac. You may want to use `garamondx` since you have to install additional fonts anyway. The script will let you install a number of fonts. `garamondx` is an extension of `garamond`.

Comment: I got it working! Thank you so much! The only thing I still would hope to change is the looks of the Abstract. I wish for the "Abstract" to look like a chapter heading but without numbering and not appearing in the ToC. Is this possible?

Comment: @user2927919 Great! See my update. In that case, don't bother with the `abstract` environment. Just use an unnumbered chapter (which won't appear in the toc by default). The `*` makes the chapter unnumbered.